# How to animate an update of the flex container width based on the change of an angular component's variable

Tags: css, angular, animation, css-animations, keyframe

Consider a container, which contains an icon as well as a label next to the icon. The container has a flex-Layout, which means its width is adjusted to the width of its content. I am only displaying the label if a boolean variable "showLabel" is set in my ts-component. This is simply done by adding `*ngIf="showLabel"` to the label inside my HTML file:

```
  <div class="container">
    <i class="material-icons">{{ iconName }}<i>
    <label *ngIf="showLabel">{{ label }}</label>
  </div>
```

I can toggle the "showLabel" variable upon clicking a button. In this case, the width of the container shrinks, since the label disappears. I would like to animate this process, while at the same time not specifying any hard coded width. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: You can do that with Angular animations. Are you familiar with it ?

Comment: no, just had to look it up. I will take a closer look though, thx a lot!